# Prove or disprove if $a\mid b+c$, then either $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove the following statement, otherwise give a counter example
>   If $a\mid b+c$, then either $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c.$

I could disprove this using a counter example.
Let's say $b=67,c=1,a=2$.

$2$ divides $67+1=68$. However, $2$ does not divide $67$ or $1$.

Is this a good counter example? Is there a better way of disproving this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a good counterexample, and what is a bad one? It should be correct, this is the most important part. Yes, $2\mid 67+1$, but not $2\mid 1$ or $2\mid 67$. Of course, one can take an "easier" counterexample, e.g.,
$$
2\mid 3+3
$$
but $2\nmid 3$.

Comment: Why not $2\mid 1+1$?

Comment: Because $1$ is not a prime. So we see it is not even true for primes $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine.
$\text{ }$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider $b=a+1$ and $c=a-1$.